# How does a trusted user remove their delete vote on an answer?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

For [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/6028/99) on the Anime & Manga SE site, I cast a delete vote due to a misunderstanding about the deletion policy. This misunderstanding has now been cleared, and I have come to conclusion that the answer should not be deleted. How do I remove my delete vote? I couldn't find any obvious way of doing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't - but the vote won't hurt anyone: Without at least two deletion votes the answer will not be deleted. Also, if it ever reaches a non-negative score nobody besides a diamond moderator will be able to cast another delete vote on it.

The only way to get rid of the delete vote would be a moderator or the author of the answer to delete the answer and then undelete it again.